# Firebase crashlytics does not report all the crashes

Tags: firebase, crashlytics-android

I have integrated the Firebase Crashlytics in my project. It worked fine when I tested the integration. A few crashes are reported there. But I noticed that not all app crashes are being reported in Firebase console. There are a few crashes that I can see are reported in the Google Play console but not in Firebase console.

I am using compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'

Any pointer? Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you perhaps expecting to see ANRs from Google Play?

Comment: Sorry for updating late. Got a reply from the guys @ google... According to them the crash(a rare one) occur before firebase crashlytics are being initialized....

Comment: @AmeyBhandarkar can you confirm if the crashes present on google play console are part of firebase crashlytics reports as well although not visible on Firebase crashlytics logs?